# How to block a key in TChromium?

Tags: delphi, events, key, tchromium

Here is my code :

```
procedure PreKeyEvent(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
  const event: PCefKeyEvent; osEvent: PMsg;
  out isKeyboardShortcut, Result: Boolean);
begin
    if (event.windows_key_code = VK_CONTROL) or
    (event.windows_key_code = VK_RMENU) or (event.windows_key_code = VK_LMENU) then
  begin
    event.windows_key_code := 0;
  end;
end;
```

The `IF` block works fine. But this line [`event.windows_key_code := 0;`] won't ignore the specified keys. How can I disable some keys using the event `PreKeyEvent`?

**Edit :**
I have also tried to set `Result` parameter to `true`. still does not work.

Comment: The [`OnPreKeyEvent`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefKeyboardHandler.html#OnPreKeyEvent) has no description, but I guess it works the same way as any other handler in the framework; to indicate that you've handled the event you return true to the result, false otherwise.

Comment: Tried that already. doesn't work.

Comment: Well, you should say so in your question. If the rest of the framework works that way, I don't see why you chose the way of assigning 0 to the key code. Personally, as first I would try to return true to the result, if that won't work I would search the issue tracker.

Comment: @TLama However, none of these solutions work. any other suggestion?

Comment: The `OnPreKeyEvent` event is commented in [`the source`](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/d7f7c61ddd3428880e37459a6b0c7dd902bf9532/include/cef_keyboard_handler.h?at=master) as *"Called before a keyboard event is sent to the renderer. |event| contains information about the keyboard event. |os_event| is the operating system event message, if any. Return true if the event was handled or false otherwise. If the event will be handled in OnKeyEvent() as a keyboard shortcut set |is_keyboard_shortcut| to true and return false."*

Comment: If your handler is properly attached, that is, your code executes and gets to the branch which returns `True` to the `Result` parameter, it should eat the key before it gets to the renderer. That way should work. If not, it might be a bug. However, I'm not sure which keys are handled that way. I have seen example which works with the `osEvent` parameter (there you should see the raw Windows message). But I don't have CEF nor Delphi by hand to test this right now.

Comment: P.S. my next (and last) guess is that the keys you are trying to handle are not processed this way, that the `windows_key_code` is not filled with any of these keys. Maybe you can try to inspect what's inside the `osEvent` parameter when the `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` message is sent ([`something along these lines`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23669888/960757)). Or maybe you'll need to follow the comment about the `is_keyboard_shortcut` parameter is you're about to handle shortcuts. `</any other wild guess suggestion>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, As I realized it's not possible to disable the `Ctrl` or the `Alt` key separately. Instead, there is a `native_key_code` that presents an Integer value for any kind of pressed key on keyboard (shortcuts have different codes). You can simply print `native_key_code` values for yourself and see the related generated codes.

So in my case I just needed to disable `Ctrl+A` and `Ctrl+C` shortcuts :

```
procedure PreKeyEvent(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
  const event: PCefKeyEvent; osEvent: PMsg;
  out isKeyboardShortcut, Result: Boolean);
const
  CtrlA = 1966081;
  CtrlC = 3014657;
begin
  if (event.native_key_code = CtrlA) or (event.native_key_code = CtrlC) then
  begin
    Result := true;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but 1966081 is actually the key code for A not CTRL+A.